# RESTful API return child entity

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I am designing a web api where clients can retrieve information about a course.
In my model the entity course has several properties including the property instructor. Instructor is a class on it's own.

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double? Duration { get; set; }
    ...
    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
}

public class Instructor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My question is, should i return all of the instructors properties when calling the course controller, set instructor to null or don't i retrun it at all?
Or are there any other options?

I have no idea what best practice is in this case. When the child entity is a collection i usualy just return an empty array. But in this case there is only 1 so i can't return an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best practice is to serialize that child entity, only if it's needed on client side when returned from this request. otherwise, you're just transferring unnecessary data.

to make the application decide whether or not to serialize it, (using Newtonsoft) you can implement a custom data contract resolver and use it when serializing your entities:

```
public class CustomDataContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if ((property.DeclaringType == typeof(Course) ||
            property.DeclaringType.BaseType == typeof(Course)) &&
            property.PropertyName == "Instructor")
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize =
               instance =>
               {
                   return true; // or false
               };
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```